# java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, arrays, linkedhashset

I want to write a java program that will give me frequency of letters in a given `String`.

I have tried this:

```
public void frequencyOfLetter() {
    String strMOd[] = "Hurricane.".split("");
    LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = (LinkedHashSet<String>) Arrays.asList(strMOd);
for (String letter : lhs) {
        if (lhs.contains(letter)) {
            System.out.println(letter + " " + Collections.frequency(lhs, letter));
        }

    }


}
```

Why I am using `LinkedHashSet` because I do not want any duplicates. However this is giving me error that this kinda casting is not correct.

So I used this as few extra line of code:

`List<String> lhs =  Arrays.asList(strMOd);
LinkedHashSet<String> lhsmod = new LinkedHashSet<String>(lhs);`

Why previous code was giving that error and what is the better of doing it with help of `LinkedHashSet`?

Comment: your question title says it all.. wrong casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast will fail because two types are unrelated: `LinkedHashSet` is neither a supertype nor a subtype of `Arrays$ArrayList`, so there is no way that a reference to an `Arrays$ArrayList` can contain something which can be cast to a `LinkedHashSet`.

You can very easily create a LinkedHashSet from an array:

```
LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(strMOd));
```

The difference between this code and your previous code is that this code creates a new instance of `LinkedHashSet`, copying in the elements of the list.

Comment: Please explain **unrelated**.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` is neither a supertype nor a subtype of `Arrays$ArrayList`.

Comment: If it is that obvious why it doesnt give compile time error (A zigzag red line below the error ).

Comment: Eclipse gives me a warning about an unchecked cast.

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

First, `Arrays.asList(strMOd)` returns you `ArrayList` which is inner class defined in `Array.java` and it cannot be casted to `LinkedHashSet` as both are different types.

Second, for your example you dont need to do any casting or conversions.
`ArrayList`  returned by `Arrays.asList` implements `List<>`, and `Collections.frequency` accepts anything which implements `Collection` and as `List` extends that interface you could do that.

```
String strMOd[] = "Hurricane.".split("");
        List<String> lhs = Arrays.asList(strMOd);
        for (String letter : lhs) {
            if (lhs.contains(letter)) {
                System.out.println(letter + " "
                        + Collections.frequency(lhs, letter));
            }

        }
```